# converting string of unicode "\u0063" into "c"

Tags: java, string, unicode

I'm doing some cryptoanalysis homework and was trying to write code that does a + b = c. My idea was to use unicode.  b +(b-a) = c. Problem is my code returns a the unicode value of c not the String "c" and I can't convert it.

Please can someone explain the difference between the string below called unicode and those called test and test2? Also is there any way I could get the string unicodeOfC to print "c"?

```
//this calculates the unicode value for c
String unicodeOfC = ("\\u" + Integer.toHexString('b'+('b'-'a') | 0x10000).substring(1));

//this prints \u0063
System.out.println(unicodeOfC);

String test = "\u0063";

//this prints c
System.out.println(test);

//this is false
System.out.println(test.equals(unicodeOfC));

String test2 = "\u0063";
//this is true
System.out.println(test.equals(test2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between `test` and `test2`. They are both `String` [literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) referring to the same `String`. This `String` literal is made up of a [unicode escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-UnicodeEscape).

> A compiler for the Java programming language ("Java compiler") first
>   recognizes Unicode escapes in its input, **translating the ASCII
>   characters `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits to the UTF-16 code
>   unit (§3.1) for the indicated hexadecimal value**, and passing all other
>   characters unchanged.

So the compiler will translate this unicode escape and convert it to the corresponding UTF-16 code unit. That is, the unicode escape `\u0063` translates to the character `c`.

In this

```
String unicodeOfC = ("\\u" + Integer.toHexString('b'+('b'-'a') | 0x10000).substring(1));
```

the `String` literal `"\\u"` (which uses a `\` character to escape a `\` character) has a runtime value of `\u`, ie. the two character `\` and `u`. That `String` is concatenated with the result of invoking `toHexString(..)`. You then invoke `substring` on the resulting `String` and assign its result to `unicodeOfC`. So the `String` value is `\u0063`, ie. the 6 characters `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `6`, and `3`.

> Also is there any way I could get the string `unicodeOfC` to print "c"?

Similarly to how you created it, you need to get the numerical part of the unicode escape,

```
String numerical = unicodeOfC.replace("\\u", "");
int val = Integer.parseInt(numerical, 16);
System.out.println((char) val);
```

You can then print it out.

Comment: Excellent, I understand your answer and appreciate the additional code which works how I want it to.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not understanding how string escaping works.

In Java backslash is an escape character that allows you to use characters in strings like newlines `\n`, tabs `\t`, or unicode `\u0063`.

Suppose I am writing code and I need to print a newline. I would do this `System.out.println("\n");`

Now lets say I want to show a backslash, `System.out.println("\");` will be a compile error but `System.out.println("\\");`  will print `\`.

So your first string is printing the literal backslash character then the letter u then the hexadecimal number.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of \n etc so when you put it like this it makes sense.